# gapi is undefined sometimes in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, gmail-api

I'm making an app in angular 6 which logs in user using Google API. Everything is being implemented and working fine, But problem occurs when sometimes `client` library does not gets loaded and it says
**gapi is undefined**. I'm loading script in `index.html` using `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js" async defer></script>`

I also tried downloading lib to local and added it in `angular.json` like:

```
"scripts": [
          ...
          "src/assets_v2/js/gmail_client.js",
        ]
```

But this is also causing same issue i.e loading it sometimes and sometimes not. Is there any way to load `client` lib before angular app initialized? how can I make sure that lib gets loaded first and then app should be initialized. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `async` and `defer` from the script tag:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```